# Why am I getting this 'undefined' error?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, iron-router

I'm working on a Meteor project, and for some reason this profile template refuses to work.

I'm using the following code, as well as the `accounts-password` and `accounts-entry` packages for user management:

```
this.route('profile', {
    path: '/profile/:username',
    data: function() {
        var userDoc = Meteor.users.findOne({"username": this.params.username});
        var bookCursor = Books.find({owner: userDoc._id});
        return {
            theUser: userDoc,
            theBooks: bookCursor
        };
    }
});
```

When I try to go to the profile URL for my test accounts ('misutowolf', and 'test2', respectively), I am given the following error in Chrome's dev console: `Exception from Deps recompute function: TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of undefined`, pointing to the use of userDoc._id in the call to `Books.find()`.

This makes no sense whatsoever, as I was able to find a user document with the names in question using `meteor mongo` with both usernames, in the form `db.users.find({username: "misutowolf"})` and `db.users.find({username: "test2"})`.

I am very confused, not sure what is causing this issue at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default Meteor only publish the currently logged in user info via an automatically setup publication.

What you need to do is push to the client the user info (`username`) you're trying to use, because if you don't do that, the user you're accessing is not published to the client and you get an undefined error when accessing its `_id`.

First, setup a dedicated publication (on the server) :

```
Meteor.publish("userByUsername",function(username){
  return Meteor.users.find({
    username:username
  });
});
```

Then `waitOn` this publication in your route :

```
waitOn:function(){
  return this.subscribe("userByUsername",this.params.username);
}
```

Finally, guard against accessing the user document until it is pushed to the client because even if you are waiting on the subscription, the `data` method might actually get called even if the subscription is not ready yet.

```
data: function() {
  var userDoc = Meteor.users.findOne({"username": this.params.username});
  if(!userDoc){
    return;
  }
  // ...
}
```

Comment: You're awesome!   I never thought to mess with publications/subscriptions because I still have autopublish enabled in my project.  I guess I just figured it did stuff with Meteor.users as well, but I was wrong.

Thanks so much, you've saved me a few times recently.  :)

Comment: _guard against accessing the user document until it is pushed to the client_ is best accomplished by using the [loading hook](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router#controlling-subscriptions); just add `Router.onBeforeAction('loading')` anywhere on the client and use your `data` function as usual.

Comment: From my experience, adding the `loading` hook doesn't prevent the `data` method from getting called before the `waitOn` list is ready.